# After updating dropdown value is still the same

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter project with Firestore. There are form with the dropdown.

When I change value in dropdown Firestore receives new value but there are no changes in the interface. So I can't see new value in the interface. It seems like the issue is not with changing the currency itself, but rather with how the selectedCurrency state is being updated and used within the DropdownButton. How I may fix it?

```
const List<String> accountCurrencyOptions = <String>[
  'USD',
  'EUR',
  'TRY',
];
const String defaultCurrency = 'EUR';

final accounts = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('accounts');

Future<void> updateAccount({
  required String documentId,
  required String accountCurrency,
}) async {
  try {
    await accounts.doc(documentId).update({
      currencyFieldName: accountCurrency,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    throw CouldNotUpdateAccount();
  }
}

class CreateUpdateAccountScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateUpdateAccountScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateUpdateAccountScreen> createState() =>
      _CreateUpdateAccountScreenState();
}

class _CreateUpdateAccountScreenState extends State<CreateUpdateAccountScreen> {
  CloudAccount? _account;
  String selectedCurrency = defaultCurrency;

void onCurrencyChanged(String? newValue) async {
  final account = _account;
  if (account == null || newValue == null) {
    return;
  }

  await _accountsService.updateAccount(
    documentId: account.documentId,
    accountCurrency: newValue,
  );

  setState(() {
    selectedCurrency = newValue;
  });
}

Future<CloudAccount> createOrGetExistingAccount(BuildContext context) async {
  final widgetAccount = context.getArgument<CloudAccount>();

  if (widgetAccount != null) {
    _account = widgetAccount;
    selectedCurrency = widgetAccount.accountCurrency;
    return widgetAccount;
  }

  final existingAccount = _account;
  if (existingAccount != null) {
    selectedCurrency = existingAccount.accountCurrency;
    return existingAccount;
  }

  final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;
  final userId = currentUser.id;
  final newAccount = await _accountsService.createNewAccount(userId: userId);
  _account = newAccount;
  return newAccount;
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('New Account'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: createOrGetExistingAccount(context),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.done:
                return DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: selectedCurrency,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    onCurrencyChanged(newValue);
                  },
                  items: accountCurrencyOptions.map((String currency) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: currency,
                      child: Text(currency),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              default:
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```